# Gathering data from datagrid in a specified column and row

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

In my WPF application I am browsing database in a datagrid. The point of my code is to store selected cells content in datagrid to some list of values for further operations. My code works well for selected items under 12, but for more items it throws an `NullRefferenceException` that says "

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Thank you for help.

code:

```
List<string> graphValue = new List<string>(dataGrid1.SelectedItems.Count); //create list 
IList someList = new ArrayList(dataGrid1.SelectedItems); //define Ilist
DataGridColumn dataGridCol = dataGrid1.Columns[listBox1.SelectedIndex]; 
//select column whom i wana collect data

if (dataGrid1.SelectedItems != null)    //when selection applied..
{
   for (int i = 0; i < dataGrid1.SelectedItems.Count; i++) //go row by row in selected column above
   {
      try
      {
         id = ((TextBlock)dataGridCol.GetCellContent(someList[i])).Text.ToString(); //save cell content to string
         graphValue.Add(id); //add value to Ilist
      }

      catch (Exception ex)
      { 
         System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "error"); }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: don't manipulate UI elements in code in WPF. Learn MVVM. Create a proper ViewModel to hold your data. The visual Tree is too complex and your code that contiously casts visual elements into what you expect to be there is really very error prone. It reduces scalability by forcing UI elements to actually be in the place the code expects them to be.

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception?  Something is returning `null`...

Comment: exception is thrown at this line:
`id = ((TextBlock)dataGridCol.GetCellContent(someList[i])).Text.ToString();`
but none of the input values are `null`
I just sefect more data input (more rows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was googling and I found solution for me. I will give it here for the others. I would appreciate, if someone can explain me what I did wrong in the previous code upper.

This code works for me:

```
if (dataGrid1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)    //when selection applied..
  {
   for (int i = 0; i < dataGrid1.SelectedItems.Count; i++) //go row by row in selected column above
      {
       try
         {
          System.Data.DataRowView selectedFile = (System.Data.DataRowView)dataGrid1.SelectedItems[i];
          string str = Convert.ToString(selectedFile.Row.ItemArray[listBox1.SelectedIndex]);
          graphValue.Add(str);
         }
       catch (Exception ex)
         { System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "error"); }
      }
```

Now I can select in `DataGrid` more rows than 10.
Refference to: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/119505/Get-Selected-items-in-a-WPF-datagrid
Now I am really happy, thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 1):

#### This simple code may help you Here first we are going to loop through each record of Data-grid Then select specific cell/column data with loop by Providing Row , and Column as..

```
for(int row =0; row < dg_CountInventory.Rows.Count; row ++)
{
TextBlock b = dg_CountInventory.Columns[1].GetCellContent(dg_CountInventory.Items[row ]) as TextBlock;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you define your `someList` with

```
IList someList = new ArrayList(dataGrid1.SelectedItems);
```

You actually create an `ArrayList` with all values are `null`. After that, you try to archive `GetCellContent()` method with it.

```
dataGridCol.GetCellContent(someList[i])).Text
```

`someList[i]` is probably `null`, that's why you get `NullRefferenceException`. Add some values of this array before use it.

Comment: yes, I thought the same, but none of objects `System.Data.DataRowView` in someList are null, so I am trying to use relevant data. Can problem be in `TextBlock` or somewhere else ?

Comment: edit: I actually create an `Arraylist` with selected rows from `DataGrid` by property `datagrid1.SelectedItems`. All selected rows contains data, every column, every cell. Problem will be in some basics that i cant see, because I just start with C# and I am learning by myself so sorry for inconvenience.